# Repeatedly measuring the same observable on the same system

Tags: quantum-mechanics, time-evolution, quantum-measurements

Suppose we have got some operator $A$ which does not commute with the Hamiltonian, for example $\hat{p}_{x}$ and $\hat{H}$, where $\hat{p}_{x}$ does not commute with the $\hat{H}$ and we make the first measurement and we get $p_{x}^{\prime}$ and immediately after the first measurement the system's momentum is in the eigenstate $|p_{x}^{\prime}>$ according to  a postulate of quantum mechanics. What if I continue to measure the same operator $\hat{p}_{x}$ again and again. Shouldn't the state remain in the same eigenstate if I keep repeating the measurement for an indefinite length of time as long as I keep measuring the same operator ie. $\hat{p}_{x}$. How can this occur because the operator doesn't commute with the Hamiltonian, so we should see the system evolve or change with time in the Schrodinger picture?

Comment: Worth looking up the quantum zeno effect.

Comment: Just did that thanks for mentioning

Answer (score 2):

Suppose the time between each measurement is $\Delta t$. Your first measurement puts the system in some eigenstate $|a\rangle$. After a time $\Delta t$, the state has time-evolved to the state $|a'\rangle=e^{-i\hat{H}\Delta t/\hbar}|a\rangle$. This has an easy expression in the basis of energy eigenstates $|E_n\rangle$:

$$|a'\rangle=e^{-i\hat{H}\Delta t/\hbar}|a\rangle=\sum_ne^{-iE_n\Delta t/\hbar}\langle E_n|a\rangle|E_n\rangle$$

Suppose you're interested in the probability that you measure your observable to be $b$, which is associated with the eignenstate $|b\rangle$. The probability of measuring your observable to be $b$ is then:

$$|\langle b|a'\rangle|^2=\bigg|\sum_ne^{-iE_n\Delta t/\hbar}\langle E_n|a\rangle\langle b|E_n\rangle\bigg|^2$$

Now suppose that you want to see what the probability is that you'll still measure the observable to be $a$ after a time $\Delta t$. Assigning $b=a$ in the above expression, we see that, in general, the probability is a sum of a bunch of interfering terms with different angular frequencies, which means that you **might not measure the same value** after a time $\Delta t$.

Comment: Except the states $a^{\prime}$ and b are orthogonal so the LHS of the the second equation is either equal to 1 if b=a and 0 otherwise.

Comment: Again supposing that b is an Eigenstate of the same operator in question

Comment: @user11937 $|a'\rangle$ and $|b\rangle$ are **not** necessarily orthogonal since the system has evolved, $|a\rangle$ and $|b\rangle$ are orthogonal since they **are** eigenstates of the same Hermitian operator.

Comment: What is it then a superposition of eigenstates of the operator? This can’t be possibly true since the measurement axioms says that after a measurement the system jumps to an eigenstate of the same operator.

Comment: The eigenstates of a Hermitian operator are orthogonal so you can always use them as a basis. The evolved state can be written as a linear combination of the eigenstates of that observable, but that's nothing special.

Comment: @user11937 For any operator that doesn't commute with the Hamiltonian, time evolution **will** create a superposition of eigenstates for most points in time, even if you start out with an eigenstate of that operator. This is because the only states that _don't_ evolve into a superposition with time are the energy eigenstates (the "stationary states" of the Hamiltonian), and, since this operator doesn't commute with the Hamiltonian, we know that its eigenstates aren't generally energy eigenstates.